# `this` is not being bound in prototype method

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, arrow-functions, stealjs

I have some weird issue an arrow function:

Arrow functions are supposed to have a context of this bound when in a prototype method (es6 class method in this case), but in this case the 'this' is undef inside the 1st lambda

```
 apply(bookings) {
    if (!bookings.length) {
      return
    }
    bookings.forEach(booking=> {

  //this is undef here

      let matchingTimeSlot = this.timeSlots.find(item=>item.bookingDate.isSame(booking.bookingDate))
    })
```

`apply` is being called from another es6 class:

`this.days[i].apply(currentDaysBookings);`

Comment: Show us how you call `apply`, please. I'm sure `this` is `undefined` outside of the arrow function as well.

Comment: Arrow functions are not supposed to have `this` "bound" to anything. No, they are supposed to have *the same `this`* as their lexical parent function.

Comment: @Bergi   at this line `this` is defined : 

`bookings.forEach`

Comment: How do you know? You're not using it, are you? Are you sure that `currentDaysBookings` is defined?

Comment: @Bergi I'm sure, I used a debugger, yes `currentDaysBookings` is defined

Comment: Can you show us the transpiled code, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this is undef here

Please note that your debug tools might be lying to you. `this` will actually get transpiled to `_this` or something like that. You should look at the generated JavaScript. I can assure you that it will have `_this` (or whatever its called) pointing to the right thing.

Comment: Ok I noticed that _this is correct, so the bug is in babel then? Why wouldn't babel transpile it to this? How am I supposed to know its _this?

Comment: so now I need to change my code from `this.timeSlots ` to `_this.timeSlots `, this seems very sad..